# How I can I characterize the treasury yield curve as one number?

Tags: modeling, econometrics

We know when the treasury yield curve inverts it is a sign that the economy is headed for trouble. I would like to analyze the relationship between the yield curve and the economy. My problem is coming up with a method to describe the shape of the yield curve using one number. I'd like to do something a little more complex than just measuring the slope between the near and far term instruments. Any suggestions?

Comment: The maturity corresponding to the highest yield?

Comment: What is the reason you need to use just a single number to describe the yield curve?

Comment: Using the maturity is an interesting idea but a tad simplistic. There are MANY shapes to the yield curve and a small number of maturities. Just using the maturity wouldn't give me any insight into the severity of any backwardation.

Comment: My thought was I could create something of a yield curve index. I could take that index and then throw it against some algorithms. My thought was it would be much simpler to reduce the yield curve to a single variable as opposed to 4 or 5. My thinking being that the results would be much cleaner instead of being confused by having some portions of the yield curve have a pattern in the analysis while other portions do not.

Comment: What shape format for the US treasure yield curve would work best for you? some examples are continuous variable between -1 and 1; continuous variable between 0 and 100; continuous from negative to positive infinity; categorical variables such as normal, steep, flat, humped, inverted.